# How to count the results from a Custom Entity using JPA CriteriaQuery

Tags: jpa, criteria-api, jpa-2.1

I am using JPA2.1 criteria API where in I have created a result object using criteria builder construct.

Consider the below sample piece of code.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb;//Assume cb is obtained here 
CriteriaQuery<Report> cq = cb.createQuery(Report.class);// custom selective Class
Root<Student> root = cq.from(Student.class);
Join<Student, XTable> join1 = root.join("xtable", JoinType.INNER);
Join<Student, YTable> join1 = root.join("ytable", JoinType.INNER);
```

Below is the main line where I would select.

```
cq.select(cb.construct(Report.class,
      root.get("name"), join1.get("address_type"), join2.get("country")));
```

Now, I would like to do a count on this construct `Report`.

I tried count like this.

```
cq.select(cb.count(cb.construct(......)));
// Failed because count accepts Expression and I tried assigning the cb.construct to Expression which is not working.
```

How to get the count?

Comment: Add more details about the entity classes and their relationships. Tell us about class `CandidateReport`: what's the purpose of it? Is there an db table representing it? What's the purpose of using `CriteriaQuery#getRestriction()`, since there is no `where` clause in `cq`?

Comment: And why are you showing 2 queries when the question says you need only the count query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it would look something like this:

Your code:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb;//Assume cb is obtained here 
CriteriaQuery<Report> cq = cb.createQuery(Report.class);// custom selective Class
Root<Student> root = cq.from(Student.class);
Join<Student, XTable> join1 = root.join("xtable", JoinType.INNER);
Join<Student, YTable> join1 = root.join("ytable", JoinType.INNER); 
countItemsByCriteria(entityManagerReference, cq, cb);


private <T> Long countItemsByCriteria(EntityManager em, CriteriaQuery<T> cqEntity, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = cb;
    CriteriaQuery<Long> cqCount = builder.createQuery(Long.class);
    Root<?> entityRoot = cqCount.from(cqEntity.getResultType());
    cqCount.select(builder.count(entityRoot));
    cqCount.where(cqEntity.getRestriction());
    return em.createQuery(cqCount).getSingleResult();
}
```

As also described in this post: [JPA + Hibernate count(*) using CriteriaBuilder - with generatedAlias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363634/jpa-hibernate-count-using-criteriabuilder-with-generatedalias)

Comment: I tried myself for 1 hour but the criteria queries are way too complicated :D This solved my problem in 5 minutes. Thanks.